# Issue with document type name containing special characters - elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

Consider the below document mapping:

```
{
    "admin/user" : {
        "properties" : {
            "message" : {"type" : "string", "store" : "yes"},
            "user_id" : {"type" : "long", "included_in_all" : "false"}
        }
    }
}
```

If we have a forward slash in the document type, how do I access the user_id type in the search query? I have another document with similar user_id field so can't just directly use the user_id in the field value.

Need to use this in term filter.

I have already tried "admin/user.user_id" and "admin%2Fuser.user_id". But none seem to work in my case.

Elasticsearch version: 0.90.1

Using Tire Ruby client (version 0.4.3). I know this is pretty old version, but can't think of moving to new tire version as of now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "admin/user.user_id" in term filter actually worked. I forgot to reindex the data after the change in the mapping...Thats really dumb, I know.